# change label value using value stored at session

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, session-scope

i have two jsf pages (home.jsf and employees.jsf) ,
home page has a button that navigates to employees page,
while navigating i store value in session scope
at (Managed bean)

```
    public void putSessionAL(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("key","value");
}

public String navigate() {
    return "employees";
}
```

i want to change Label at employees viewObject from UIHints tab depending on value stored at session using the following groovy expression

```
adf.context.sessionScope.key
```

and changed trustMode to trusted but it fires the following exception

```
oracle.jbo.script.ExprScriptException: JBO-29114 ADFContext is not setup to process messages for this exception. Use the exception stack trace and error code to investigate the root cause of this exception. Root cause error code is JBO-25188. Error message parameters are {0=Employees.FirstName, 1=, 2=oracle.jbo.script.ExprSecurityException}
at oracle.jbo.script.ExprScriptException.throwException(ExprScriptException.java:316)
at oracle.jbo.script.ExprScriptException.throwExceptionWithExprDef(ExprScriptException.java:387)
at oracle.jbo.ExprEval.processScriptException(ExprEval.java:599)
at oracle.jbo.ExprEval.doEvaluate(ExprEval.java:697)
at oracle.jbo.ExprEval.evaluate(ExprEval.java:508)
at oracle.jbo.ExprEval.evaluate(ExprEval.java:487)
at oracle.jbo.common.NamedObjectImpl.resolvePropertyRaw(NamedObjectImpl.java:680)
at oracle.jbo.server.DefObject.resolvePropertyRaw(DefObject.java:366)
```

Comment: why not having the bean linked to home.jsf in a RequestScope so you can get the value in employee.jsf from the bean and not from the session. (Figure 21-3 Relationship Between Scopes and Page Flow : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/web.1111/b31974/adf_lifecycle.htm#ADFFD521). Storing in session must be avoided if not for user related not critical data. Are you sure storing in session is the right approach ?

Comment: yes, i want data to be stored in session . it's releated to users.
i can change it from page properities with expression #{sessionScope.key}, but it will take time to change them at every page 
i need to handle them once from viewObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it at the VO UIHint attribute label level will be programmaticaly by doing as follow :

- In your VO go to the java tab and add the RowImpl java class
- In the VORowImpl Add the following function

  ```
  public String getMySessionLabel() {     
      return (String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("key");
  }
  ```
- In the Label add the following EL expression :

  ```
  adf.object.getMySessionLabel()
  ```

This technique allow you more control than pure EL, if you want to do more than getting from session for example. In your case pure EL, as you did, should work as well. (Would need to check what is wrong with yours, maybe just missing the

```
        #{adf.context.sessionScope.key}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to get your label from a method in viewRowImpl. So this will be executed at least once for each row. I think this solution isn't fit for your case.

anyway ADF as a framework added strong policy and validations in EL in general and especially in version 12.2.x.

The solution for you case as following:

1. Create new class in model layer which extends oracle.jbo.script.ExprSecurityPolicy class
2. Override checkProperty method.

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean checkProperty(Object object, String string, Boolean b) {
       if (object.getClass().getName().equals("oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFContext") && string.equals("sessionScope")) {
           return true;
       }
       return super.checkProperty(object, string, b);
   }
   ```
3. Open adf-config.xml source and in startup tag set your class ExprSecurityPolicy property.

like:

```
<startup ExprSecurityPolicy="model.CustomExprSecurityPolicy">
```